# How to get only the initial NaN values and leading non NaN values from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe where the rows contain NaN values. The df contains **original columns** namely **Heading 1 Heading 2 and Heading 3** and **extra columns** called **Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 and Unnamed: 3** as shown:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading 3 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | 45 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 24 | 45 | 11 | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 45 | 45 | 33 |
| 4 | NaN | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 22 | 34 | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 34 | NaN | 45 | NaN | NaN |

I want to **iterate through each row** and find out the amount of **initial NaN values** in **original columns (Heading 1 Heading 2 and Heading 3)** and the amount of **non NaN values** in the **extra columns (Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 and Unnamed: 3)**. For each and every row this should be calculated and **returned in a dictionary** where the key is the index of the row and the value for that key is a list containing the amount of **initial NaN values** in **original columns** (Heading 1 Heading 2 and Heading 3) and the second element of the list would the amount of **non NaN values** in the **extra columns** (Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 and Unnamed: 3).

So the result for the above dataframe would be:

```
{0 : [1, 1], 
1 : [2, 2], 
2 : [3, 3], 
3 : [0, 0], 
4 : [2, 0], 
5 : [1, 0],
6 : [0, 0],
7 : [1, 1]}
```

Notice how in row 3 and row 7 the original columns contain 1 and 2 NaN respectively but only the initial NaN's are counted and not the in between ones!

### UPDATE / RESULTS:

Both @mozaway and @Panda Kim gave the correct solution for the current dataframe but @mozway solution does not work at all for another test dataframe.

@Panda Kim gave 2 solutions but both the methods he gave (cumsum() and x.first_valid_index()) are giving slightly different results for the different dataframe.

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading 3 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | 45 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 24 | 45 | 11 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 45 | 45 | 33 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 22 | 34 | 24 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 34 | NaN | 45 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12 | 22 | 45 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 11 | 69 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12 | NaN | 45 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 45 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 44 | NaN |

For the above df here are the results:

@Panda KIM (first_valid_index())

```
{0: [1, 1], 1: [2, 2], 2: [3, 3], 3: [0, 0], 4: [2, 0], 5: [1, 0], 6: [0, 0], 7: [1, 1], 8: [3, 3], 9: [3, 2], 10: [3, 2], 11: [3, 1], 12: [3, 1]}
```

@Panda Kim (cumsum())

```
{0: [1, 1], 1: [2, 2], 2: [3, 3], 3: [0, 0], 4: [2, 0], 5: [1, 0], 6: [0, 0], 7: [1, 1], 8: [4, 3], 9: [5, 2], 10: [4, 2], 11: [6, 1], 12: [5, 1]}
```

@mozway solution

```
{0: [1, 1], 1: [2, 2], 2: [3, 3], 3: [0, 0], 4: [2, 0], 5: [1, 0], 6: [0, 0], 7: [1, 1], 8: [3, 0], 9: [3, 0], 10: [3, 0], 11: [3, 0], 12: [3, 0]}
```

Comment: Can you provide a dictionary/DataFrame of the input? Also can the headers be identified with a specific criterion (is is always non-"Unnamed" and "Unnamed"?)?

Comment: The input is the dataframe in the question. From the df we have to get the number of initial NaN in original cols and non nan from extra cols. The extra cols will always be Unnamed: 1, Unnamed: 2 and so on but the original cols can be named anything. But for the sake of this question we'll assume they are named as Heading 1 and so on

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my answer below only relies on the "Unnamed" start of name

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
m = df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')

out = (df
   .groupby(m, axis=1)
   .apply(lambda g: (g.notna() if g.name else g.isna())
                     .cummin(axis=1).sum(axis=1)
          )
   .set_axis(['named', 'unnamed'], axis=1)
 )
```

Output:

```
   named  unnamed
0      1        1
1      2        2
2      3        3
3      0        0
4      2        0
5      1        0
6      0        0
7      1        1
```

#### as dictionary

```
out.T.to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{0: [1, 1],
 1: [2, 2],
 2: [3, 3],
 3: [0, 0],
 4: [2, 0],
 5: [1, 0],
 6: [0, 0],
 7: [1, 1]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution did not work for test dataframes. I have updated my question with the results if you are interested in taking a look. Anyway +1 for your time and effort bud!

Comment: @lowkey then your "*find out the amount of initial NaN values in original*" description seems misleading (what means **initial**?)

Comment: initial means all the NaN values before a non NaN value. Notice in the first df row 3 has NaN values but they are not initial. The first element is a non NaN value an after that element NaN values are occurring. Similarly in row 7, there are 2 NaN values but only the first one is counted since the other NaN value occurs after a non NaN value.